# Get the first and last day of the workweek when a date is given

Tags: php, date, laravel-blade

I am trying to get the first day of the week(Monday) and the last day of the workweek(Friday) when I give a date. Normally the date that is given is the date of Monday but there are exceptions.

The date given is for example 2019-04-18. 
The last day of the workweek here is 2019-4-19 and the first is 2019-4-15.
I'm working in laravel and would like to use it in a blade template so if possible I would like to do it in like one line of code if possible.

I am able to get the last day of the workweek but still have trouble with the first day. I am also not certain that the way I get the last day is the best.

```
{{ date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(($overtime->workdate). ' + '.(5-date('w', strtotime($overtime->workdate))).' days')))) }}
```

The problem with the answers that have been given is that I am trying to get it all in one line in a blade template so I cannot make a new DateTime or something. It starts with a string that gives a date.

Comment: Not sure why 2 negative votes, question is perfectly fine and understandable.

Comment: I have read those answers but I am trying to make it fit in one line to use in a blade template. If it is not possible I will try something else, just wanting to know I it is possinle

Comment: What is the problem with doing it in blade template? See the answer below on how to do it via Carbon

Comment: You shouldn't do these date calculations/manipulations in blade. You should send the final data from your controller into the blade view. If you absolutely must do this on the fly in blade, create a Helper class and make it available in the view, then do something like `$dateHelper->startOfWeek($date)` (or do it with a Carbon instance directly, as answered below)

Comment: I had hoped I could use it like this but it seems like I will have to change it in my controller. I think that will go faster than writing a helper class. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use carbon to achieve this,

```
$date = new Carbon('2019-04-18'); // 

// To get the first week of the day we can do this
echo $date->startOfWeek(); // 2019-04-15
echo $date->endOfWeek(); // 2019-04-19
```

If you are unaware of Carbon, here is the [doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to help you out.